# GeoServer CSS encoding

Tags: geoserver, encoding, geoserver-css-module

When using SLD as style format the head has an ecoding tag. Having title text  in "foreign" charters in GetLegendGraphic is rendered as expected.
But when using CSS format `/* @title red line åæø */`,

[image]

Is it possible to define correct encoding also for CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Copy/pasted that title in a GeoServer 2.21-SNAPSHOT (development series) deployed in Tomcat on Java 11 and... it works:

[image]

Maybe it's the version of GeoServer that's too old, or the Java version, or the default charset of the OS? Unsure.

Comment: Good point! It might be an old version I am runing, will check!